# Generate audio files using Festival

Tags: bash, festival

Is it possible to generate audio files in Festival by piping the output to some other program? I'm trying to find out how to convert an xml file to a audio file, using Festival's "singing synthesis" option.

Comment: More information here: http://festvox.org/docs/manual-1.4.3/festival_29.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a file called "america1.xml", you would use this command: `text2wave -mode singing america1.xml -o america1.wav` to generate a wav file.

I found this information here: http://festvox.org/docs/manual-1.4.3/festival_29.html